# Pinch and Zoom on Mac OS X 10.5

Tags: osx-leopard, zoom

I was wondering how do I set Pinch and Zoom back on a MacBook running OS X 10.5 because somehow I have disabled it and I would like it back.

Comment: This might be more at home on apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preference is probably in the Trackpad pane of System Preferences (I think that's there in 10.5?). You can also try the Mouse pane, and the [Advanced tab of the Finder preferences](http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1826923).

Comment: I can't find it there